# radio button selection decides next page

Tags: java, android, radio-button

i am new to android programming. I am trying to write my code so that the user makes a selection out of two radio buttons then clicks a "next" button. The next button then takes the user to one of two pages based on which radio button was selected.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/Yes"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yes" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/No"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Next"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next" />
```

-

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
    }
```

I have looked around and found nothing answering this problem.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RadioButton radioYes = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Yes);
RadioButton radioNo = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.No);
```

// in Button onClick()

```
if(radioYes.isChecked()){
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, PageOne.class);
    CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}else if(radioNo.isChecked()){
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, PageTwo.class);
    CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select the radio button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

In your onClick() method check which RadioButton is clicked as below.

```
RadioButton rbtnYes = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Yes);
RadioButton rbtnNo = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.No);
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(rbtnYes.isChecked())
{
//Navigate to your firstpage
}
else
{
//Navigate to your second page
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
private RadioButton button1 = null;
private RadioButton button2 = null;
```

in the onCreate() :

```
button1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtnButton1);
button2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtnButton2);
```

In next's onClicklistener :

```
if(button1.isChecked()) {
   // intent to page 1
} else if(button2.isChecked()) {
   // intent to page2
}
```

An another way to do that is (still in next's onClickListener) :

```
RadioGroup g = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.YOURRADIOGROUPID);
Intent i; 
switch (g.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
{
case R.id.BUTTON1ID
 //intent page 1
i= new Intent(this, ActivityForButton1.class);
break;

case R.id.BUTTON2ID
 //intent page 2
i= new Intent(this, ActivityForButton12.class);
break;
}
StarActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this

```
int radioButtonID = radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
```

and then you can check which button is checked and you can navigate accordingly.